# Как отследить что пользователь нажал и отпустил карту Google map API v2?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, java

`onMapClick` не подходит, потому что если прислонить палец к карте он не срабатывает, `onMapLongClick` тем более. Если слушать `onCameraChange` прикосновение будет срабатывать с опозданием. А мне надо сразу же, чтоб дотронулся и запустилась функция, опустил карту запустилась вторая функция. Как это сделать?

Короч отвечаю на свой вопрос в тут, т.к. не хватает очков уважения. Решение не для всех, но думаю для решения задачи новичков, оно вполне подойдет.

Сначала переопределяем события нажатий у меня в (главном активити) после онкриейт.

```
    @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_MOVE");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_UP");
            break;
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

}
```

Ай да я ай да молодец)

У MotionEvent куча есть всего тут я показал перетаскивание пальца по экрану ACTION_MOVE оно вызывается кучу раз сразу после нажатия ACTION_DOWN, отпускание пальца от экрана ACTION_UP
Еще ссылки по теме:
[link text](http://src-code.net/ispolzovanie-sensornogo-ekrana/)
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722869/how-to-handle-ontouch-event-for-map-in-google-map-api-v2)